# Абсолютное позиционирование

Tags: css

Всем добрый день столкнулся с небольшой проблемкой в верстке. Есть див в нем все дивы с абсолютным позиционированием у самого дива позиционирование `relativ`. Например когда в диве используется `float:left` и тд что бы его растянуть в высоту нужно использовать например `clear:both`. Есть ли подобное свойство только для дивов с абсолютным позиционированием ??

Answer (score 1):

Элементы с абсолютным позиционированием выпадают из потока элементов вообще. Они ни на что не влияют, и на них ничто не влияет. Зачем вам clear both в абсолютном позиционировании? И приведите пример вашего кода на jsfiddle, например

Comment: Clear:both мне в абсолютном позиционировании не нужен я прекрасно знаю что это для сброса обтекания. но задача слудующая есть две колнны допустим левое меню и справа контентовая область а в контентовой области все идет с абсолютным позиционированием и нужно левую колонку растянуть на такую же высоту как правая но правая по сути получается не имеет высоты вообще отсюда и казус.

Comment: Вам же говорят, приведите пример кода

Comment: @alexsis20102, ну тогда как вариант высоту родителя выставлять как сумму высот всех дочерних элементов + пару пикселов. естественно это все на js или jquery

Comment: да не хотелось на JS делать но придется потому что с помощью CSS это не решить.. Спасибо всем

Answer (score 0):

- Если разговор про 2 или 3 ( или N ) колонок, то не пользуйтесь абсолютным позиционированием,, отсюда "родительский" блок перестанет схлопываться.
- Если "в общем" то схлопываение родительского блока неизбежно при отсутствии элементов, отличный от position absolute\fixed.
- Приведите код